# Laravel 5.2.x Password Broker using Username as the Email Column name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We're inheriting a CakePHP code base, and a schema.  Porting it to Laravel 5.2.x, but we have to maintain the schema where they use username in the schema instead of email.  So I'm trying to get password reset to work using the username column instead.

I've pulled in ResetPasswords::sendResetLinkEmail into the PasswordController to overwrite it and validate on username instead of email, and pass in username to sendResetLink so the user can be authenticated:

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('username'), $this->resetEmailBuilder()
    );

    // ...
```

But, it throws an error after invoking the method on line ~91 in the PasswordBroker:

```
$token = $this->tokens->create($user); // line 91
```

Now I have no idea where this goes since it appears to be invoking an interface that is dependency injected into the PasswordBroker, but it is responsible for saving the password reset record.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of fussing around I figured it out.  In order to keep the semantic column username instead of using email for password reset:

There are two steps:

1) You need to pull up `ResetsPasswords::sendResetLinkEmail` into your PasswordController, and have it validate and pass in username to sendResetLink, which is in the question, but also included below for completeness:

```
/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('username'), $this->resetEmailBuilder()
    );

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);

        case Password::INVALID_USER:
        default:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
    }
}
```

2) The key to this, which seemed to take a while to figure out yet is quite simplistic in nature, but completely undocumented as far as I can tell is changing the trait `CanResetPassword::getEmailForPasswordReset` used on the User model to also use username instead of email, which you don't want to overwrite within CanResetPassword so I removed the trait from the User model and applied my own copy of it within the application namespace:

```
namespace App\Traits\Auth;

trait CanResetPassword
{
    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
}
```

Now you can send password reset links, and reset passwords.  Hope this helps.